# Command "textScaler" is not defined

Tags: dart

i am currently on a Dart project with a friend and he used a lot the textScaler command. But my Dart does not know the command.
I keep getting this message.

> The named parameter 'textScaler' isn't defined. Try correcting the
> name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named
> parameter with the name 'textScaler'.dart (undefined_named_parameter)

Answer (score 0):

## Error

```
problem in 0.65.0 not working on flutter 3.13.2 need flutter 3.16    Error: Type 'TextScaler' not found.  TextScaler textScaler
```

## Fixed by using version 0.60.0

Full example

```
fl_chart: 0.60.0
```